# Parsing Python response.text

Tags: python, parsing

I am new in Python, and I need a little help.

I have a script:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.example.com/vtapi/v2/ip-address/report?apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ip=8.8.8.8"
r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
print(r.text)
```

the printed response is:

```
{"asn": 45899, "undetected_urls": [], "undetected_downloaded_samples": [{"date": "2019-07-25 00:55:11", "positives": 0, "total": 70, "sha256": "FDFEFDSFgrgd"}], "country": "VN", "response_code": 1, "as_owner": "VNPT Corp", "verbose_msg": "IP address in dataset", "detected_downloaded_samples": [{"date": "2020-10-13 06:47:34", "positives": 35, "total": 74, "sha256": "dfghdfghdfghdfgh"}], "detected_urls": [{"url": "http://8.8.8.8/", "positives": 3, "total": 79, "scan_date": "2020-10-13 21:27:33"}, {"url": "https://8.8.8.8/", "positives": 3, "total": 79, "scan_date": "2020-10-13 16:10:11"}, {"url": "http://8.8.8.8:49594/Mozi.m", "positives": 2, "total": 79, "scan_date": "2020-10-13 15:47:47"}, {"url": "http://8.8.8.8:49594/Mozi.m/", "positives": 1, "total": 79, "scan_date": "2020-10-13 15:43:04"}], "resolutions": []}
```

So, the data i need to parse, starts with  `"detected_urls":` and contains `[{"url": "http://8.8.8.8/", "positives": 3, "total": 79, "scan_date": "2020-10-13 21:27:33"}`, `{"url": "https://8.8.8.8/", "positives": 3, "total": 79, "scan_date": "2020-10-13 16:10:11"}`, `....etc.......` It may be 1,2,3-10-20 blocks, but i need to take(pay attention) **only the first block**, like `[{"url": "http://8.8.8.8/", "positives": 3, "total": 79, "scan_date": "2020-10-13 21:27:33"}` , and parse `"positives": 3` data.

Then,

If there is no `"detected_urls":` clause in the response, so there must be `print "Session closed"` ;

If `"positives"`count is more then `0`, so the following script must starts:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.example2.com/api/v2/report?apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&data=runData"
r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
print(r.status_code)
```

Thats all))

*P.S. Please use as few modules as possible, because my system(that uses Phython) may not support them!*

Thanks to All!

Comment: does `r.json()` return a JSON object? it looks like the text is valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

So like gold_cy mentioned in the comments, instead of parsing the data as text, you can just convert the response content to JSON which will allow you to access information like your typical dictionary.

So you could easily accomplish this like so:

```py
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
res_json = response.json()

if len(res_json['detected_urls']) == 0:
    # Do stuff
    ...
else:
    # Get the first item from detected_urls
    first = res_json['detected_urls'][0]
    # Do stuff...
```